# Pull to refresh (SwipeRefreshLayout) android xamarin c#

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to add the pull to refresh in home page screen.

In the beginning, the axml is:

[initial code](https://pastebin.com/vQju5SDw)

```
  [1]:https://pastebin.com/iZNFiqgt
```

i added the the swipeRefreshLayout so:

[Code SwipeRefresh](https://pastebin.com/vQju5SDw)

In the class i added this code:

```
............

SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout

protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
.........

refreshLayout = FindViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout> . 
(Resource.Id.swipeRefreshLayout1);

refreshLayout.Refresh += RefreshLayout_Refresh

}

void RefreshLayout_Refresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //insert action pull to refresh 
Console.WriteLine("start pull to refresh"); //after delete it and 
insert the action 

}
```

But the app crash when I try to pullRefresh the page. The error is :

[image: Error]

Thanks all for the support!!

Comment: Place listing view inside `SwipeRefreshLayout` and check.

Comment: I added the ListView:
https://pastebin.com/dYDzUai6

but i had the same error. what do you think about it?? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SwipeRefreshLayout` should be used whenever the user can refresh the contents of a view via a vertical swipe gesture. [Read more](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout)

So, `SwipeRefreshLayout` behaves like a container, so inside the `SwipeRefreshLayout` you should add a `ListView` or `GridView` in order to make it work, as you can see below:

> Remember that `SwipeRefreshLayout` only supports a single `ListView` or `GridView` child.

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
     android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <ListView 
         android:id="@+id/list"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

  </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And then, setup your view elements:

```
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
ListView listView;    

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   // ...

   listView = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.list);
   swipeRefreshLayout = view.FindViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout>(Resource.Id.swipeRefreshLayout);

   // Elevation helps users understand the relative importance of each element and focus their attention to the task at hand. (Optional)
   // swipeRefreshLayout.Elevation = 10; 

   swipeRefreshLayout.Refresh += delegate (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
      // logic...
   };

   // ...
}
```

Also, you can trigger the `SwipeRefreshLayout` manually, via:

```
swipeRefreshLayout.Post(() => { 
   swipeRefreshLayout.Refreshing = true; 
   listView.Clickable = false; 
});

// logic...

swipeRefreshLayout.Post(() => { 
   swipeRefreshLayout.Refreshing = false; 
   listView.Clickable = true; 
});
```

I hope this can help you.